# Quarkus separate main/test META-INF\services implementations

Tags: quarkus

I need two separate implementations for a org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigSource so I have them in the usual way under main and test. The problem is that when I run "quarkus test", the main one is picked up. If I remove the main one, the test one is picked up fine so there is apparently some precedence going on

What would be the correct way to have separate implementations picked up for test and prod?

Thanks in advance,
Nik